# lubuntu/linux symbolic link default application

Tags: linux

Being new to Linux I have been enjoying making plenty of educational mistakes. The most recent is with a misunderstanding of symbolic links. Trying to open a symbolic link with leafpad offered no means to edit the link as well as set a default applicaation to open all symbolic links (at least on the desktop). How do I dereference symbolic links in Lubuntu so they will work again? I currently get a blank Leafpad document when I open symbolic links.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "dereference a symbolic link so it will work again?" - do you mean remove a symbolic link or point it to another location?

Comment: using the gui lubuntu offers an option to open the file using an applicsation. I cannot use the symlink without the application taking over and failing. I do not know what, if any, application to connect a symlink to in order to have it open like a shortcut. I cannot figure out how to remove the default application so the OS can handle it as before.

Comment: What I mean is that the symbolic link is now default opened by the notepad app, while dereferencing it from the notepad and back to wherever it is supposed to be pointing. Since placing this question I have just never used symbolic links. Sure the OS might be, but that is not what I was having trouble with. Don't worry, the fact that I could not phrase the question at the time only shows that it was obviously of no importance. And knowing how to make new symbolic links is of little use when they just open notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Ive never really come across setting or modifying symbolic links in linux via a gui (Im sure there probably is one though)

#### 1. You can make a new symlink in the terminal with:

(note dont enter the $ - I just put it there to indicate the command needs to be run in a shell)

`$ ln -s /folderPathOfTarget/file nameOfYourSymlink`

#### 2. remove symlink

`$ rm nameOfYourSymlink`

.
If you want to rename - delete as per 2. create new symlink as per 1.

Comment: I have deleted and recreated the link several times with the result being a new symlink opened by the leafpad. I do not know if this affects all symlinks as I don't know of any others to try.

Comment: are you sure its a symlink and not an application launcher? - they are different things in ubuntu/linux.  You can tell its a launcher in unity desktop by the fact it will end in `*.desktop`

Comment: if the command ln -s /[path] /[target] can create an application launcher then that may be the problem, however the properties tab describes it as a symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, a symbolic link is simply a new name (pointer, link) to an existing file. So the program you're using to open a symbolic link would be the same program you use to open the original file.

You can create a symbolic link to any type of file, directory, etc. So if have an existing text file, and you correctly create a sym. link to that file, both files should open with leafpad.

However if you're expecting to use leafpad to manipulate symbolic links (create, delete, etc) that won't work.

Comment: That was the educational part of my experience. I now know how to remove and create new links, which is what I wanted to do now that I know better. The target is an application launcher that is no longer targeted by any symbolic links from the desktop. The Leafpad is now default application for all calls to open symbolic links.